# Find the lowercase (un-shifted) form of symbols

Tags: python, string

```
x = "Foo 890 bar *()"
```

How can I get the lowercase including the `"*()"` being 'unshifted' back to `890`? Desired result:

```
foo 890 bar 890
```

Unwanted:

```
x.lower() => "foo 890 bar *()"
```

Comment: Layout of keyboard are different in different languages. I think there is no such fucntion. Not sure though. You can hardcode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unshifting depends on keyboard layout. It's not a universal mapping. You could hardcode one.

```
unshift = {
    '!': '1', '@': '2', '#': '3', '$': '4', '%': '5',
    '^': '6', '&': '7', '*': '8', '(': '9', ')': '0',
}

x = ''.join(unshift.get(c, c.lower()) for c in x)
```

An alternative, more compact way to write that map would be:

```
unshift = dict(zip('!@#$%^&*()', '1234567890'))
```

Comment: Im neck deep in windows API at the moment so getting the keyboard layout isn't a problem. This is the way I'm doing it right now but it just feels... awkward :S

Answer (score 2):

#### Python3

You could use `str.translate` if you want to avoid explicitly disassembling and assembling strings in your code.

(Assuming the same keyboard layout as in John Kugelman's answer).

You could subclass `dict` to handle the common case - a key's shifted and unshifted values are upper and lower case versions of the same character - automatically and use this as the translation table.

```
class Unshift(dict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        """Given an ordinal, return corresponding lower case character"""
        return chr(key).lower()

specials = {
    '!': '1', '@': '2', '#': '3', '$': '4', '%': '5',
    '^': '6', '&': '7', '*': '8', '(': '9', ')': '0',
}

unshift = Unshift((ord(k), v) for k, v in specials.items())

>>> x.translate(unshift)
'foo 890 bar 890'
```

However this is performs slightly more slowly than John's approach - I expect because of the cost of the lookup misses and the calls to `chr`.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import unshift, x', stmt='x.translate(unshift)')
7.9996025009895675

>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import d, x', stmt='"".join(d.get(c, c.lower()) for c in x)')
7.469654283020645
```

Performance greatly improves if you can create a mapping with all combinations, avoiding the cost of failed lookups.

```
>>> import string
>>> # Example dict 
>>> d2 = {ord(c): c.lower() for c in (string.ascii_letters + string.digits)}
>>> d2.update((ord(k), v) for k, v in specials.items())

>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import d2, x', stmt='x.translate(d2)')
0.8882806290057488
```

#### Python2

`str.translate` takes a translation table as its argument; the table must be constructed using `string.maketrans`.

```
>>> d2 = {c: c.lower() for c in (string.ascii_letters + string.digits)}
>>> d2.update(specials)
>>> items = sorted(d2.items())
>>> src, dest = ''.join(x[0] for x in items), ''.join(x[1] for x in items)
>>> tt = string.maketrans(src, dest)

>>> x.translate(tt)
'foo 890 bar 890'
```

`str.translate` in Python2 is faster than in Python3

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import tt, x', stmt='x.translate(tt)')
0.2270500659942627
```

however the `string.maketrans` and `str.translate` combination in Python2 doesn't seem to handle unicode very well, so they may not be suitable if you are dealing with international keyboards.